# Command prompt cannot find file specified

Tags: c#, command-prompt, sqlcmd

I'm trying to create a utility to auto restore lots of databases but I'm stuck. It's either the path of SQLCMD or the command string is wrong. The `Win32Exception was unhandled`

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified

The string is working on command prompt but not on my application.
On the command prompt

```
SQLCMD -E -S Ge\sqlexpress -Q "RESTORE DATABASE dbName FROM DISK='C:\app\dbName_300915_000.bak'"
```

On my application

```
@"SQLCMD -E -S Ge\sqlexpress -Q ""RESTORE DATABASE dnName FROM DISK='C:\app\dbName_300915_000.bak'"""
```

I replaced the `SQLCMD` with the full path

```
@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE -E -S Ge\sqlexpress -Q ""RESTORE DATABASE dbName FROM DISK='C:\app\dnName_300915_000.bak'"""
```

still not working. Could it be multiple `SQLCMD` ??

The code for my app is

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"SQLCMD -E -S Ge\sqlexpress -Q ""RESTORE DATABASE dnName FROM DISK='C:\app\dbName_300915_000.bak'""");
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        var proc = Process.Start(psi);

        string s = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        textBox2.Text = s;
```

Comment: Just remove arguments from exe name
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5zzxthe(v=vs.110).aspx

`ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("SQLCMD",@"-E -S Ge\sqlexpress -Q ""RESTORE DATABASE dnName FROM DISK='C:\app\dbName_300915_000.bak'""");`

Comment: And will be good to redirect sderr too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason this code

```
using System.Diagnostics;
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.Start();
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo Oscar");
cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
cmd.StandardInput.Close();
cmd.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

Found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32872174/3424327 works!

Answer (score 0):

I think each double quote has to be surrounded by a set of double quotes. I see only two double quotes in front of RESTORE.
Try this:

```
@"SQLCMD -E -S Ge\sqlexpress -Q """RESTORE DATABASE dbName FROM DISK='C:\app\dbName_300915_000.bak'""""
```

Comment: The `RESTORE DATABASE dbName FROM DISK=` so it's not part of the string